# How to use applymap in a DataFrame on condition that an element is greater than the one which is at the same column but last row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df`, say, 100 rows and 10 columns. I would like to get values on condition that an element in each column is greater than the element in that column but last row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'a': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 4},
    'b': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 6},
    'c': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 4},
    'd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 6},
})
```

from the 2nd row, index = 1, I have to judge that, for each column

1. if the 3rd row is greater than 2nd row, return diff
2. if the 3rd row is smaller than 2nd row, return sum
3. if the 3rd row is equal to 2nd row, return 0

for example, I would like to get

```
df_outcome = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'a': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 2},
    'b': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 4},
    'c': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2},
    'd': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 5},
})
```

because

```
df.iloc[2,0] < df.iloc[1,0]
df_outcome.iloc[2,0] = df.iloc[2,0] + df.iloc[1,0] = 3 + 2
```

also because

```
df.iloc[2,2] > df.iloc[1,2]
df_outcome.iloc[2,2] = df.iloc[2,2] - df.iloc[1,2] = 2 - 1 = 1
```

Yeah, I use an awkward way to achieve this. I wonder whether `.applymap` is available in this case. If it is, how could I code that `func` which contains the element last row at the same column?

The complicated original code is as followed.

```
weightMatrix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((100,10)))

def func(weightMatrix):
    cfList = pd.DataFrame(weightMatrix,columns = weightMatrix.columns)
    for col in range(len(weightMatrix.columns)):
        for row in range(len(weightMatrix)):
            if row == 0:
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = weightMatrix.iloc[row,col]
                continue
            if (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col] * weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] > 0 ) & (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col]>0 ):
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = np.max(weightMatrix.iloc[row,col] - weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col],0)
            elif (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col] * weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] > 0 ) & (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col]<0 ):
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = np.max(weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] - weightMatrix.iloc[row,col],0)
            elif (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col] * weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] == 0 ) & (weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] == 0 ):
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = np.abs(weightMatrix.iloc[row,col])
            elif (weightMatrix.iloc[row,col] * weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] == 0 ) & (weightMatrix.iloc[row-1,col] != 0 ):
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = 0
            else:
                cfList.iloc[row,col] = np.abs(weightMatrix.iloc[row,col])
    return cfList
```

Comment: Consider reading [mcve] and [edit]-ing your post.  As it is, I'm highly discouraged to wade through your code to figure out what you are doing.

Comment: sry, how about it now? Is it much more clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a row with the previous or next row, `df.shift()` is your friend
If you want to do things depending on certain conditions, `df.where()` can help you

```
df1 = df.shift(1,).iloc[1:].astype(int)
df2 = df.iloc[1:]

result = df2.copy()
result = df2.where(df1!=df2, 0)
result = (df2 - df1).where(df1 < df2, result)
result = (df1 + df2).where(df1 > df2, result)
result = pd.concat((df.iloc[[0]], result), axis=0)
```

> ```
>   a   b   c   d
> 0 1   1   0   0
> 1 2   3   1   0
> 2 5   6   1   1
> 3 2   4   2   5
> ```

PS. I think your `df_outcome` is wrong for element `d2`, If not, I missed something in  your explanation